# Using while to get 13 digits

Tags: asp.net

I am new to programming, I need to generate 13 random number using loop (while) number + 1 when the number reaches 13, I will like to store that number in text box.
Any help will be welcomed

Answer (score 1):

What you see below is a 'static' class, which needs no initialization. So, with this in your project, you can just call RandomInts.GetRandomInts() and pass it on into your model for the input box to present to your user(s).

```
public static class RandomInts
{
    private static int _x = 0;

    public static int GetRandomInts()
    {
        var i = 0;
        var rnd = new Random();

        while (i < 13)
        {
            _x = rnd.Next();
            i++;
        }

        return _x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is with upper and lower bounds:

```
var x = random.[Next](minr, maxr)
```